# Laravel 5 - skip migrations

Tags: php, laravel

I have migrated an existing Laravel 5 application and database. Only no migrations table was there yet, so I created this with the following command:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

Inside the database migration folders three files exist (2015_12_08_134409_create_tables_script.php, 2015_12_08_134410_create_foreign.php, 2015_12_08_134411_create_index.php)

When using 'php artisan migrate' the scripts inside the migrations folder are executed again. This is what I want to avoid. Is it possible to insert records in Laravel's migrations table, so these scripts will be skipped and new scripts will be picked up once 'php artisan migrate' is executed again?

Comment: did you look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations#database-seeding

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Once you have the migration table created, insert these records:

```
insert into migrations(migration, batch) values('2015_12_08_134409_create_tables_script',1);
insert into migrations(migration, batch) values('2015_12_08_134410_create_foreign',1);
insert into migrations(migration, batch) values('2015_12_08_134411_create_index',1);
```

So artisan will understand those migrations as 'executed'

Comment: Perfect! The result is now: 'Nothing to migrate.' Thanks a lot!

Comment: When insert the record to migration table, the batch value (e.g. as 1 above) should be next batch number.

Comment: Thanks! I've inserted all my already done migrations and It worked, thanks. FWIW, I prefer starting with 0 as the batch value is the database was migrated and for any reason `migrations` table was not there or empty.

Comment: This was a top tip that helped me skip some migrations that had happened to one db in our landscape. Thanks Sergio.

Answer (score 16):

Another way is just create a folder under `database/migrations` to put you want skip migrations, this method works for both files that have been migrated or not yet migrated.

```
# Execute commands in laravel project root folder
mkdir database/migrations/ignored
mv database/migrations/2018_08_14_000000_should_ignore_migration.php \
   database/migrations/ignored/

# Check migration has been skipped
php artisan migrate:status
```

---

### 2018-09-25 update:

This [Artisan CLI extension command](https://github.com/caloskao/migrate-specific/) is support single command to migrate specific files on Laravel 5.4 or later:

```
# Install extension
composer require caloskao/migrate-specific

# Migrate
php artisan migrate:specific /path/to/migration_file.php
```

Comment: Moving migrations to another folder will break Laravel's ability to roll them back if they had already been applied. I'm not going to upvote an answer that breaks the program's ability to do what it was designed to do.