# Laravel remove pending migration execution

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two Laravel apps that use the same database. I moved migrations from app 1 to app 2.
Now I want to remove the pending migrations from app 2 due to that I moved the migrations files to it and tables exists in database.

Is any way to remove them from pending execution when `php artisan migrate` is executed?

Regards

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115541/laravel-5-skip-migrations/51838111

Comment: Thanks @Berto99 this workrd too, is the same approach. Sorry I read first Kirmin post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the migrations manually in the migrations table in the database, and that way they will be marked as executed.
Note that i assume both apps do not use the same database migrations table.

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, can you sign my answer as answer for this question

Comment: Thanks @Kirmin the approach suggested worked perfect!