# Prevent application of a specific database migration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have several database migrations coded in Laravel that I do *not* want to apply just yet.

- I do not want to rename these files or move them into some other folder. If any of the migrations had been applied previously, moving or renaming them breaks Laravel's ability to roll them back.
- I do not want a means of applying only one specific migration at a time.
- I want a means of marking the class that is a modification to the migration file itself, not some external marking or process (such as adding rows to the `migration` table).

Is there a programmatic solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 - skip migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115541/laravel-5-skip-migrations)

Comment: No. The question given there is "Is it possible to insert records in Laravel's migrations table, so these scripts will be skipped and new scripts will be picked up once 'php artisan migrate' is executed again?" The answer given involves adding records to the migrations table. I'm looking for something that can be done to the class files themselves. (TBH, the ability to disable migrations by moving them to a subfolder is closer, but it's still a hack.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer : [Laravel 5 - skip migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838111/19887183) may be of help for you, instead of skipping , choose the migrations you want to do directly .

What I'm referring too exactly is the use of `caloskao/migrate-specific`

Comment: That provides for running specific migrations, not marking migrations to be skipped.